# make text change color at different screen size with animation using keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to make text of the `div` change text `color` when it gets to different screen size because my webpage has a picture viz making the text not readable.

I've used `@media` and `@keyframe` `CSS` animation to achieve that but it doesn't work, maybe there's something I'm missing.

`HTML`:

```
<div class="container-fuid section section-contact" id="contact">
    <div class="row text-center">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                <h3>
                    Looking for a quo<span class="span1">te for your next</span> <spanclass="span2">project?</span>
                </h3>
                  <address>
                    <strong><i class="icon-phone"></i> PHONE NUMBER:</strong><br>
                       <span>0000000000000</span><br>
                    <strong><i class="icon-envelope"></i> EMAIL:</strong<br>
                     <strong> <a href="mailto:hello@me.com">hello@me.com</a></strong>
              </address>
      </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
.section.section-contact{
    width:100%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: #fe523e;
    margin: 0;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-image:url('../img/contact-right.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 70.05%;

}

@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 900px) {
.section.section-contact{
    background-size: 100%;

  }
}
.section.section-contact div {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.section.section-contact h1{
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #083858;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.section.section-contact h3{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #083858;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;

}

/** make text color change at different screen size BEGIN */

.section.section-contact .span2{
    animation-name: span2; 
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@media (max-width: 1356px) {
    .section.section-contact .span2{
    @keyframes span2 {
          from {background-color: whitesmoke}
          to {background-color: #083858;}
        }
    }
}
.section.section-contact .span1{
    animation-name: span1; 
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .section.section-contact .span1{
    @keyframes span1 {
          from {background-color: #083858;}
          to {background-color: whitesmoke;}
        }
    }
}
/** make text color change at different screen size  END*/
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your `keyframes` outside the `media` query, and then copy your animation-name, iteration-count, etc codes inside the `media` query

```
@keyframes span2 {
          from {background-color: whitesmoke}
          to {background-color: #083858;}
        }

@media (max-width: 1356px) {
.section.section-contact .span2{
    animation-name: span2; 
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
}
    @keyframes span1 {
          from {background-color: #083858;}
          to {background-color: whitesmoke;}
        }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.section.section-contact .span1{
    animation-name: span1; 
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5ert5pb/) - you will see I've decreased the `width` to `300px` and `600px` in the media queries so that you can easily view the change is happening or not.

Comment: thanks it worked. is there a way i can remove the blink and just change the text color only?

Comment: @codecraft to change `text-color` and not `background-color`?? for that use `color: #083858;` instead of `background-color` in `keyframes`, also for the instant blinking of `background-color`, you should use this in the `keyframes` - `0%,100% {color: whitesmoke;} 50% {color: #083858;}`, remove the original `from` and `to`

Comment: I have done that, but What i wanted was just to change the text color upon screen reduction without any kind of blink.

Comment: @codecraft done what? coloring of text? also I think you mean to not have that instant blinking animation? instead a smoother fade from whitesmoke to #083858 and then from #083858 to whitesmoke.. do you want that smooth fading upto infinite times??

Comment: @codecraft do you want this - http://jsfiddle.net/k5ert5pb/1/ OR this - http://jsfiddle.net/k5ert5pb/2/

Comment: Yes I could test out both options see which fits best. thanks a lot bruv.

Comment: @codecraft consider selecting answer as best answer if you find any, otherwise provide your persisting problem in detail..

Answer (score 2):

css: you did not specify browser prefix eg. -webkit-, -moz-, -ms-
find **[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jspowqqh/)**

```
.section.section-contact{
    width:100%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: #fe523e;
    margin: 0;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-image:url('../img/contact-right.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 70.05%;

}

@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 900px) {
.section.section-contact{
    background-size: 100%;

  }
}
.section.section-contact div {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.section.section-contact h1{
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #083858;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.section.section-contact h3{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #083858;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;

}

/** make text color change at different screen size BEGIN */

.section.section-contact .span2{
    -webkit-animation: span2 5s infinite;
    -moz-animation: span2 5s infinite; 
    -ms-animation: span2 5s infinite; 
    animation: span2 5s infinite;
}

@media (max-width: 1356px) {
        @-webkit-keyframes span2 {
          from {background-color: whitesmoke}
          to {background-color: #083858;}
        }
        @-moz-keyframes span2 {
          from {background-color: whitesmoke}
          to {background-color: #083858;}
        }
        @-ms-keyframes span2 {
          from {background-color: whitesmoke}
          to {background-color: #083858;}
        }
        @keyframes span2 {
          from {background-color: whitesmoke}
          to {background-color: #083858;}
        }
}
.section.section-contact .span1{
    -webkit-animation: span1 5s infinite;
    -moz-animation: span1 5s infinite; 
    -ms-animation: span1 5s infinite; 
    animation: span1 5s infinite;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

     @-webkit-keyframes span1 {
          from {background-color: #083858;}
          to {background-color: whitesmoke;}
        }
     @-moz-keyframes span1 {
          from {background-color: #083858;}
          to {background-color: whitesmoke;}
        }
     @-ms-keyframes span1 {
          from {background-color: #083858;}
          to {background-color: whitesmoke;}
        }
     @keyframes span1 {
          from {background-color: #083858;}
          to {background-color: whitesmoke;}
        }
}
/** make text color change at different screen size  END*/
```

Comment: plus 1 for the vendor prefixes

Comment: are you sure you are not giving solved. (green mark) to anyone?

Comment: @locateganesh is there a way i can remove the blink and just change the text color only?

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/jspowqqh/1/  use keyframe in % instead of 'from and to'.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. You don't have to call the selectors again inside the media query wrapping the keyframes as you are already pointing to the relevant keyframe with the "animation-name" property

```
.section.section-contact .span2{
    animation-name: span2; 
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@media (max-width: 1356px) {
    @keyframes span2 {
          from {background-color: whitesmoke}
          to {background-color: #083858;}
    }
}
.section.section-contact .span1{
    animation-name: span1; 
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    @keyframes span1 {
          from {background-color: #083858;}
          to {background-color: whitesmoke;}
    }
}
```